# its not covering in my test class can you please anybody help me on this,

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

```java
obj = SAPIntegrationToGetMAP_SL__c.getInstance('Integration Details');
if(obj !=null){
   username = obj.Client_Id__c;
   password = obj.Client_Secret__c;  
}
```

for this have written like this

```java
@TestVisible
global HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest req){        
    SAPIntegrationToGetMAP_SL__c customsetting = new SAPIntegrationToGetMAP_SL__c();
    //objtest = SAPIntegrationToGetMAP_SL__c.getInstance('Integration Details');
    customsetting.name = 'Test Integration Details';
    customsetting.Client_Id__c = 'clientId';
    customsetting.Client_Secret__c = 'clientSecret'; 
    customsetting.API_callout_URL__c = 'https://dlsh-qas.apimanagement.ap21.hana.ondemand.com:443/prdtapi/productstock_s4hana/get';
    insert customsetting;
        
    String username,password,endpointurl;
    System.debug('customsetting'+customsetting);
    if(customsetting != null){
         username = customsetting.Client_Id__c;
         password = customsetting.Client_Secret__c; 
         endpointurl = customsetting.API_callout_URL__c;   
     }
```

but its not covering,

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, if the clientId and clientSecret posted in the question were the real ones, you should consider them compromised. Please never post valid credentials online.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a custom setting named `Test Integration Details`, but in the class you're testing the custom setting name is `Integration Details`.
The [`getInstance(dataSetName)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm#apex_System_ListCustomSetting_getInstance) method returns the custom setting data set record for the specified data set name, that's why it returns `null` during the test.

To fix this issue change `customsetting.name = 'Test Integration Details';` to `customsetting.name = 'Integration Details';`

Moreover you should insert the custom setting in the method with `@IsTest` annotation, not in the one that implements `HttpCalloutMock`.